# TYPO3: "Localize All records" and "Synchronize with original Language"

Tags: typo3

What is the difference between "Localize All records" and "Synchronize with original Language" in IREE records?

I could not find any documentation about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right, it's missing in the documentation.

`Localize all records` is the process to get all IRRE elements from the related default language into your current language (and you can translate them afterwards)

`Synchronize with original language` can be done when you have translated the elements and the content in the default language changed.

Comment: Is it correct, that "Synchronize with original language" only works for new records which have made in the original language? If I change a child record in the default language, the button "Synchronize with original language" is not available. Only when I add a news child.